# Laptop does not enter suspend state when lid is closed

Tags: display, power-management, manjaro, suspend, thinkpad

I installed Manjaro 18.0.4 (Gnome) on my [Lenovo P50](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/p50_hmm_en.pdf). After setting the NVidia graphics card as the primary card and removing all drivers for the onboard intel GPU, the laptop does not suspend when I close the lid any more. The screen turns off, tough.

All properties in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` are commented (so, defaults are in place). I tried to set `HandleLidSwitch=suspend`, but that does not work either.

In Gnome Tweak Tool, "Suspend when lid is closed" is set to true, with no effect.

What can I do to achieve the same behavior as with the integrated Intel graphics card?

Comment: Do you have an external monitor attached in?

Comment: I tried this with the laptop display only as well with an external monitor via HDMI or two external monitors via docking station / DisplayPort. Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I have had the same issue when ext. monitor connected: in that case, was not an issue but a voluntary behaviour of GNOME. Tweaking logind has not had any effect as well (probably GNOME ignore low-level stuff...)!

Answer (score 1):

The acpid daemon can trigger user defined actions (like enter suspend state by exec'ing "echo mem > /sys/power/state") when it receives [$group $action $device $id] tagged device's events (in this case it would be group=button action=lid id=close). You first identify by watching /var/log/messages and construct a config file based on it.

A ***very*** low-level solution, maybe not suited in your case. But can be helpful in case you have no other mean.

Comment: **How** would this tool help the OP solve the problem?

Comment: G-man you are right, my comment needs to be more explicative, I updated my answer!